# the usage of python join function

Tags: python, hadoop, join

I used join function to join the list in python in hadoop.But i found it is different from using join in one machine.Anyone has met this issue.
The code is that

```
def reducer():
    (last_key,last_index,list) = ("","","")
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        fields = line.split("\t")
        if len(fields) < 3:
            continue
            cur_key = fields[0]
            cur_index = fields[1]
            cur_list = fields[2]
            if last_key !="" and last_key!=cur_key:
                print "%s\t%s\t%s" %(last_key,last_index,list)
                list = ""
            elif last_index !="" and last_index!=cur_index:
                print "%s\t%s\t%s" %(last_key,last_index,list)
                list = ""
            last_key = cur_key
            last_index = cur_index
            if list != "":
                list = '_'.join(cur_list)
            else:
                list = cur_list
     print "%s\t%s\t%s" %(last_key,last_index,list)
```

I used join instead "+" because it is more efficent. But the different result when run in hadoop and in one machine.How to solve it.

The mapper output is 
key\tpos\t0000000000594720
key\tpos\t0000000000870960
cat mapper|sort|python reducer.py the result is key\tpos\tt0000000000594720_0000000000870960 it is right
But in hadoop,the result is 0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_8_7_0_9_6_0,so strange.
Hadoop can't supoort join function?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the issue is because of how you call join -

```
list = '_'.join(cur_list)
```

This would join the list cur_list , with each element having a _ in between them. So according to your code, you are getting correct result.

If you do not want anything inbetween the strings in cur_list , then use empty string for joining -

```
list = ''.join(cur_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I read the following docstring for `join` in my Python 2.7.x installation...

```
S.join(iterable) -> string

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable.  The separator between elements is S.
```

... I take it that `'_'.join('abc')` should always return 'a_b_c', because a `str` object is iterable.  And that's what I get in my Python 2.7.x installation.

I would replace your `list = '_'.join(cur_list)` line with this:

```
list += '_' + cur_list
```